# Homemade LED flashlight

Tags: led, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion

I want to make my homemade LED flashlight into an old utility light body. My plan is to use XHP70 LED from CREE (12V, 2,8A) and power it using 2S Li-Ion cells (6-8,4 V). 
My idea is to use boost converter IC to step up voltage and use shunt in series to sense current through the LED and connect it to feedback pin of the converter (and most likely use OP-AMP to amplify shunt drop voltage). At first I thought that I would use LM2577T-ADJ, but it can handle switching current only up to 3A and after some calculations it would be more to 5 amps. Is it possible to use external transistor instead of the inbuilt one? Or do you know about other IC that would do the job? MC34063 with external transistor maybe? 
Another problem is with charging. I can't seem to find any CC/CV charger IC that would be suitable for 2S cells and THT soldering. I found this circuit that could be possibility, but I would prefer to use something in small package. The charging voltage would be 12V. Thanks for any help.  [image: Possible crude li-ion charging IC]

Comment: Voting to close because questions asking for recommendations for specific products isn't encouraged.  If you *edit your question* to ask for what *qualities* you should be looking for in chips, then you'll be golden.  As for figuring out what to do -- all of the major manufacturers have selector guides for their chips; the key phrase you want is "switching controller" or "switching regulator controller".  I'm not sure you'll find what you want in through-hole, though -- it's 2020; time to learn how to deal with surface mount!

Comment: Like peufeu says, have you reasoned through **heatsinking**?  It sounds like you're just trying to slapdash a bunch of parts together to turn an old flashlight into a super flashlight.  Either you'll put thermal limiting on this and the brightness will be very lackluster after a couple seconds, or you won't and the LED will burn out.

Comment: Harper, actually yes. It was supposed to be turning an old flashlight into super flashlight for few moments before it heats up. It was planned to put a circuit that would switch the light off when heated too much and I would run it most of the time on something like 1-3 watts

Comment: There is actually quite an existing DIY LED super flashlight market.  Try some search terms like "LED boost flashlight driver".  You can buy all kinds of kits to modify existing lights or just component parts to build exactly what you want.  Note that you may want to check out "Convoy" flashlights on Aliexpress as it may be cheaper to buy what you want than modify existing product.  If you read around in the DIY community you should be able to get a good idea if the flashlight you have is suitable to modify in the first place.  You'll want to make sure you can fit it with a suitable lens.

Answer (score 1):

> My idea is to use boost converter IC to step up voltage and use shunt in series to sense current through the LED and connect it to feedback pin of the converter

I did something similar about 10 years ago, used a LTC3780 buck-boost DC-DC to make a constant current LED driver by adding a current sense amp in the feedback loop. However these days there are LED driver chips that can do all the current sensing stuff without requiring extra circuitry, so that would be a simpler and much better choice.

Now for the bad news...

Very high power flashlights usually don't have useful battery life unless they weigh a ton.

For a 30W LED, a buck converter would be more suitable and more efficient than a boost converter.

Looks like you want to use an "extreme" LED with very high power though... 30 watts...

How are you going to fit the **cooling fan** for the LED heatsink inside the flashlight?

The most important thing in a flashlight is the optics. Power is a distant second. A high power LED with wide flood beam optics will make the ground at your feet very bright, and you won't see anything in the distance. A less powerful LED with good optics will have a good throw and be much more pleasant to use.

> I can't seem to find any CC/CV charger IC that would be suitable for 2S cells and THT soldering

Seriously, if you're asking that question, I don't mean to be rude, but you sound like you should have the firemen on quick dial if you mess with lithium batteries.

Lithium cells need to be charged to a quite accurate voltage, and if the battery pack has several in series they have to be balanced. This plus adequate protection requires a complicated circuit, and the schematic in the question won't do that. If you want a readily available and **safe** lithium battery, either use the battery from your power drill and its charger, or use protected 18650 cells.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant find a THT LTC3780, but I fogot that there are also buck-boost converters, I will check those as well.

About those optics I will look at it as well, Im in the phase of planning right now.

If I use lithium cells in series the voltage I get is between 6-8 volts and the low voltage - high current version of this LED is somewhere between If I remember correctly so thats why I chose 12V one.

The body of the light is metal so Im planning to spread the heat to the body itself

And yes, the plan is to use 18650 and yes, I found a schematic for passive balancing already.

Comment: Honza, to repeat what peufeu said: 30W-capable LiIon in the same tight space like the DC/DC converter and the power LED **are dangerous**. You won't get far with through-hole. If SMD is "scary" to you, then stay away from this kind of electronics.

Comment: Yeah, I only mentioned LTC3780 as an example, I used it because I needed a light that could be powered by any voltage, so it had to be buck-boost. If you can choose the battery voltage, then use a buck regulator, not a buck-boost. Moden chips will not be available in thru-hole.

Comment: Marcus I am aware that 30W is quite a bit, and I want to implement overcharge protection of the cells, passive balancing, undervoltage and overcurrent protection as well as overheating protection for the 18650s and the LED itself and I was planning to use LT1512 for charging, but they run out of stock. I am aware that lithium cells need to be charged properly, thats why Im hesitant to use the schematic and im asking for the specialised IC instead. And its not that Im afraid to use SMD but I dont have equipment for it and I would prefer to use perfboard to change the circuit easil when needed.

Comment: Ok, you seem to not get it: **perfboard is not an option at these currents**.

Comment: Perfboard and thru hole have high inductance due to long connections. This is not compatible with modern DC-DC converters which run at high frequencies.